# Оповещения в реальном времени: TCP или UDP?

Tags: сеть, udp, tcp

Пишу сервис для синхронизации файлов: имеется сервер и большое кол-во взаимодействующих с ним клиентов; взаимодействие сводится к простому оповещению некоторых клиентов о произошедших на сервере изменениях.

Что в данном случае будет эффективнее (как по времени так и по затратам системных ресуров):

- непрерывно поддерживать с каждым клиентом TCP соединение и отправлять уведомления со стороны сервера,
- или заставить каждый клиент раз в 5-10 сек. отправлять UDP пакет с запросом на новые оповещения?

Какой подход используется для аналогичных задач: Dropbox, Jabber (уведомления о новых сообщениях), Вконтакте?

Comment: Вконтакт, Dropbox, jabber используют tcp. Но в локальной сети может быть значительно эффективнее использовать udp (мультикаст). Но только нужно помнить, что udp могут теряться.

Comment: @Jofsey, при **действительно большом** количестве клиентов (десятки тысяч) поддерживать постоянные TCP-соединения одного сервера (сетевого интерфейса) с ними со всеми не получится, т.к. размер IP порта у сервера ограничен 16 бит.

Вообще же, без более подробного описания, что Вы делаете, как эта система должна функционировать, какие требования к надежности, времени реакции в разных ситуациях и т.п. дать дельный совет не получится.

Comment: > размер IP порта у сервера ограничен 16 бит

Штоу.

2^16 — этот лимит на число соединений только для одной пары адресов (т.е. соединений на одного клиента, если не касаться NAT'ов).

Comment: Точнее это лимит на число соединений по тому сокету, который сервер использует в accept(), а вовсе не на одного клиента.

Реально это число еще меньше (порты 0-1023 и порт по которому сервер делал bind не используются).